# React: Alternative to document.createElement for simple animations?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I made a simple animation in HTML/CSS that creates particles, has them float upwards using a CSS animation, then disappear upon timeout. I want to convert this into a component for a React app, but I know directly manipulating the DOM is bad. I was able to get everything working, but I feel like using document.createElement is probably bad.
**React Code:**

```
import './ParticleWindow.css';
import React, {useRef}  from 'react';

function ParticleWindow(){

    const myBG = useRef();

    function createParticle(){
        if(myBG.current){
        const particle = document.createElement('span');
        var size = Math.random() * 30;
        particle.style.width = 20 + size + 'px';
        particle.style.height = 20 + size + 'px';
        var domRect = myBG.current.getBoundingClientRect();
        particle.style.top = Math.random() * domRect.height + 'px';
        particle.style.left = Math.random() * domRect.width + 'px';
        myBG.current.appendChild(particle);
        particle.className = "floating_particle";
        setTimeout(()=>{
            particle.remove();
        }, 5000);
        }
    }

    setInterval(createParticle, 150);


    return <div id="particle_bg" ref={myBG} className="particleWindow"></div>
}

export default ParticleWindow;
```

**CSS:**

```
.particleWindow{
    width: 90%;
    height: 600px;
    background: black;
    position: relative;
}


.floating_particle{
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    background: greenyellow;
    animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate{
    0%{
        transform: scale(0) translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    10%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    90%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100%{
        transform: scale(1) translateY(-500%) rotate(360deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Should I be using useState to instead track all the particles on screen, and then map the array inside? That seems like a highly cumbersome solution for something that's super simple without React. There are also a huge amount of particles on the screen.

Is there an alternative to document.createElement that I should be using instead? Do you notice any other issues with my code?

Please note I am trying to understand more broadly how HTML/CSS/JS animations can be transferred into React, and this is something I'm attempting as a practice exercise.

Comment: I think we can store the props of each particle to the state and render them as components.  I'll play with it.  The effect looks really cool!

Comment: After freezing my CodeSandbox many times over, I think *"That seems like a highly cumbersome solution for something that's super simple without React."* accurately sums up this question.

Comment: @LindaPaiste appreciate it :)

Comment: This is what I got before I gave up if you want to see the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-keldysh-7cg06?file=/src/App.tsx  Try to close the preview pane before it starts rendering because it will freeze lol.